# Python - tcpdump subprocess hangs

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen, tcpdump

Probably a simple fix regarding `subprocesses` but I can't work out what's going wrong.

I have a small list of webpages for which I want to packet capture. I want one `pcap` file per webpage. I'm using `tcpdump` and `phantomJS`. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
..more imports here..

URLs = ['https://webpage1.com', 'https://webpage2.com', etc.]

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/bin/phantomjs', port=65000)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)

def Crawler():
    for eachHost in URLs:
        print '\n* Capturing in-progress.'
        print '* Host: ', eachHost
        try:
            handle = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-w', str(eachHost) + '.pcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            driver.get(eachHost)
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.close()

            time.sleep(2)
            handle.terminate()
            print '* tcpdump killed.'

        except:
            print '* Exception caught.'
            sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(0)
```

**What i expect it to do**: capture first 5 seconds of each page load and put in to separate `pcaps`

**What it does**: prints the below in my terminal and then hangs, capturing but not terminating, and not cycling to the next webpage.

```
Host:  https://www.webpage1.com/
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

Comment: Did you want to sniff the ``eth0`` or the ``loopback`` interface? If your webserver is on the loopback, then specify the interface using ``-i lo``.

Comment: Hi, I'm running this script off a virtual ubuntu machine on EC2, not sure if that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you can't terminate the child process is because you're starting the process using the `sudo` command. Because tcpdump is then running as the root user, you can't just terminate it as a regular user.

I just tried testing locally. After starting tcpdump:

```
$ ps ax | grep tcpdump
62410 s007  S+     0:00.01 sudo tcpdump
62420 s007  S+     0:00.05 tcpdump
62540 s008  S+     0:00.00 grep tcpdump
$ kill -15 62410
-bash: kill: (62410) - Operation not permitted
$ kill -15 62420
-bash: kill: (62420) - Operation not permitted
```

I don't know of a way to execute a sudo kill/terminate command without forking another process (e.g., via `subprocess`), so I would have to get the tcpdump process id (`pid`) using `handle.pid` and call `subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'kill', '15', <pid>])`.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to abandon this line of thought and use scapy's sniff function to write packets directly for each loop, but the same problem occurs, and it's not even a subprocess. Weird.

Comment: Have you thought about just running the whole Python script using 'sudo', and not just the subprocess? (this is fraught with security peril, so maybe not necessarily the best advice, just so you know)

Comment: yeah I tried that first, it produces the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using handle.kill rather than .terminate?

Comment: problem solved, and like most problems it had nothing to do with what I originally thought. for some reason `driver.get(eachHost)` wasn't opening the page, not sure whats going on but changing it to `driver.get(str(eachHost))` fixed it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your subprocess call is blocking thats why you can't stop it. Try using `multiprocessing` and throw the tcpdump command into a thread.

Comment: Subprocess doesn't block like that, if memory serves me correctly. (grain of salt: it's been a while since I've mucked about with subprocess)

Comment: Dang flabbit! You're absolutely correct. I don't know why I forgot that :/